# Exportar consulta a csv con php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Tengo el siguiente código para exportar una consulta a csv con php pero no funciona, saben cómo puedo conseguir exportar la consulta a csv con php

```
 require '../conn.php';

  $sql = `(SELECT *) 
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM senders INTO OUTFILE 'prueba.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');`; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response->state = true;
    echo json_encode($response);
  } else {
    $response->state = false;
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
```

$response lo tengo declarado en "conn.php"

Comment: en `INTO OUTFILE` debes indicar la ruta absoluta de donde se va a guardar el archivo es decir debería decir `INTO OUTFILE 'C:\prueba.csv'` por ejemplo

Comment: Pero en el caso de que está en un hosting? la ruta absuluta sería el public_html? @shadow

Comment: debes indicarle el nombre de la ruta donde deseas que se exporte dicho archivo, por que esa instrucción te va a generar un archivo nuevo entonces debes declarar la ruta donde tengas permitido almacenarlo

Comment: @shadow funcionará si uso el `/` al principio para referirme a la carpeta raíz?

Cómo: `/public_html/carpeta`

Comment: no tengo al momento mayor referencia de si funcionaría así en un hosting, espero que si y me comentas si no esperamos respuestas de otros usuarios

Comment: para saber la ruta completa de donde está el script (con symlinks resueltos) podes hacer un `echo __DIR__;` o ponerlo directamente en el sql onda `$filename = __DIR__.'/prueba.csv';`